# How processing language works internally?

Tags: processing, data-visualization

Note: I am using processing jar(core.jar) on Eclipse.

Actually I want to allow user to upload location file which has city name along with location(lat and long co-ordinates) in each line. locFileSelected() is a callback method which is called once user selects file.

From above callback method, control goes to another class's (DrawOnCanvas) method readLocFileAndDraw() which does IO and creates Hashmap out of it. This map is used to iterate and draw points for each city.

Just to make sure, I drew circle in setup() methods and it works perfectly. I will explain why I used sleep() later after explaining DrawOnCanvas class.

```java
import java.io.File;

import processing.core.PApplet;

public class TestingProcessing extends PApplet{

    String locFilePath;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Applet of Processing language
        PApplet.main("TestingProcessing");
    }

    public void settings() {
        size(800,900);
    }

    public void setup() {
        background(255);

        // Just a sample ellipse, it is drawn properly.
        stroke(0);
        fill(0);
        ellipse(500,500,25,25);

        selectInput("Select a file for Locations:", "locFileSelected"); 
        // This will send control to call back method locFileSelected()

        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000); //10 sec
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("In setup()");
    }

    public void locFileSelected(File locFile) {

        // I can't draw anything here too, I tried it

        locFilePath = locFile.toString();
        DrawOnCanvas draw = new DrawOnCanvas(this, locFilePath);
        draw.readLocFileAndDraw();
        System.out.println("In callback()");
    } 


}
```

This file below does IO and I want to draw points for each city in this file itself. In this class's constructor, I have passed file path so that IO can be done respectively. In readLocFileAndDraw(), for sake of demo, I haven't done IO and also not created Map. Rather, I have just hard-coded one ellipse.

```java
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class DrawOnCanvas{

    PApplet parent;
    String locFilePath;

    DrawOnCanvas(){ }

    DrawOnCanvas(PApplet p, String locFilePath){
        parent = p;
        this.locFilePath = locFilePath;
    }

    /**
     * Reading the locations file and storing them in map 
     * @param locationsMap - Hash Map for the locations of each city in locations file
     */
    public void readLocFileAndDraw() {

        // Actually I create map here by doing Java IO for reading file
        // I iterate each line and put in a map so that for each entry, I can
        // draw a point on canvas

        parent.stroke(0);
        parent.fill(0);
        parent.ellipse(200,200,15,10);

        // Instead of reading from map which I have to do actually, I have hard-coded everything.


    }
}
```

Now, while debugging I noticed that control from setup() method goes away once user gets prompt for browsing file. For example, without sleep(), sequence of print statements is

- In setup() (this is printed first then user gets prompt)
- In callback() (this is printed after user selects location file)

Main thing is ellipse of readLocFileAndDraw() is never drawn.

Now, I have put sleep() in setup() method so that control stays there and now flow of code is

- User gets prompt, he chooses file
- "In callback()" is printed
- Total sleep of 10 seconds gets finish then "In setup()" is printed along with ellipse defined in readLocFileAndDraw() :) .

If I past the sleep time then it works exactly same as first case of without sleep 
 What is going on internally? I can sense that some threads are being dispatched but how to control it? Is there any other way to do so? Thanks.

Comment: Please see my edits to see how to properly format text in markdown.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it seems a little weird to have the callback function in a different class. It might work, but it opens up a lot of weirdness: what if you had two classes with a `readLocFileAndDraw()` function? So the first thing I'd suggest is simplifiying your design and having the callback function in the `TestingProcessing` class directly.

Secondly, it also seems weird to have a no-args `DrawOnCanvas` constructor. In that case the value for `parent` is going to be `null`, which will cause a `NullPointerException` when you try to use it. Procesing is using reflection behind the scenes, so you have to be very careful about this kind of thing.

Finally, another thing you might try is just setting some variables in your call back function and using those in the `draw()` function. something like this:

```
float x = 0;
float y = 0;

void setup() {
    selectInput("Select a file.", "fileSelected");
}

void draw(){
   background(64);
   ellipse(x, y, 20, 20);
}

void fileSelected(){
   x = 50;
   y = 50;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed feedback Sir. I was doing earlier in same file only but then also, I was unable to draw anything on canvas. I changed my code now with just one class but still have same issue. I had to literally put sleep in setup() to make it work just like I did before.
The reason I did not do in draw() is because I just want to plot cities on canvas once. When I did something in draw() then it is called again and again. Should I share my new code? Is there any other way to share with you? If required, I can edit my question and put new code here itself.

Comment: @JeetendraAhuja You can call the `noLoop()` function to stop the `draw()` function from being called repeatedly. But usually it's not a problem anyway. What code do you want to share? If you have follow-up questions, please post an updated [mcve] in its own question post.

Comment: I will try some more stuff based on your suggestions and will post  "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable" example if required. Thanks :)

Comment: Sir, I could do it in draw() method by putting some conditions at end of it so that I can execute "noLoop()" accordingly. But, still I don' understand why I had to give sleep() in setup() method to make it work. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Like I said, if you have a follow-up question, please post an updated [mcve] in a new question post. Look at my example code. It does not require a `sleep()` in `setup()` to work.